# Laravel 5.4: in Eloquent using groupBy inside of relation whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

How can I use `groupBy` in `whereHas` in Eloquent

Here is my query

```
public function index( Request $request ) {
        $dateFrom = $request->get( 'dateFrom' );
        $dateTo   = $request->get( 'dateTo' );
        $status   = $request->get( 'orderState' );

        $orders = ( new OrderList() )
            ->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
                $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id );
            } )
            ->when( $dateFrom, function ( $query ) use ( $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
                $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $dateFrom, $dateTo ] );
            } )
            ->when( $status, function ( $query ) use ( $status ) {
                $query->where( 'order_state_id', $status )->get();
            } )
            ->get();

        //dd( $orders );
        //Order Status
        $orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )->pluck( 'states', 'id' )->toArray();


        return view( 'supplierComponents.order_list', compact( 'orders', 'orderStates' ) );
    }
```

I need to group the list of the orders by `order_id` witch is exists in `orderDetail`

I have try to do so

```
->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
                $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id )->groupBy('order_id');
            } )
```

**Update**

[image: Here is the Order List]
and then

[image: Here is the Order List Details]

Order list details has `order_id` witch I need the order_list to be `groupBy` it

`dd($orders) results`

```
11 => OrderList {#723 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "orderDetail" => Collection {#741 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
```

see this

`#relations: array:1 [▼
            "orderDetail" => Collection {#741 ▼
              #items: array:1 [▶]
            }`

if it's grouped it should get the related items grouped here but it's nit happening this way

but this didn't work, what should be the right way to do it?

Comment: u will get only the orders of the looged in supplier. so what is the use of `groupBy` here? and how u are saying it didn't work?

Comment: Oh yes I get the log of the supplier but each `OrderList` has `OrderDetails` and in the `OrderDetails` each row has `order_id` related to the `OrderList` what I need is to group the order list by the `OrderDetail->order_id` so I don't get duplicated orders.

Comment: Isn't `OrderDetail.order_id` == `OrderList.id`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes this right

Comment: @arun I have update the question see the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereHas` wont give u group by, u have to get the relationship data again. use the following:

```
 $orders = ( new OrderList() )
            ->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
                $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id );
            } )
            ->with(['orderDetail' => function ($query) {
                $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id )->groupBy('order_id');
            }])
            ->when( $dateFrom, function ( $query ) use ( $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
                $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $dateFrom, $dateTo ] );
            } )
            ->when( $status, function ( $query ) use ( $status ) {
                $query->where( 'order_state_id', $status )->get();
            } )
            ->get();
```

Comment: if this isn't working then add `->get()` after the `->groupBy('order_id')`

Comment: `dd( $orders->orderDetail);` u can see this result, if it is grouped or not.

Comment: no didn't work and didn't group just saw the relation in the `dd($orders)` but not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders = Order::join('orderDetail',function($q){
  $q->on('orderDetail.your_id','orders.id');
  $q->where('supplier_id', Auth::guard('supplier')->user()->id);
})
->select(['orders.user_id','orderDetail.order_id'])
->when($dateFrom, function ( $query ) use ( $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
  $query->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [ $dateFrom, $dateTo ] );
})
->when($status, function ( $query ) use ( $status ) {
  $query->where( 'orders.order_state_id', $status );
})
->groupBy('orderDetail.order_id')
->get();
```

Comment: didn't work, and also I don't want to select from `OrderDetail` as the first table

Comment: mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: i think you don't want to use join but can you try it's working or not?

Comment: I try it bu the results is the same of course it gives errors on the blade, but comes to the `dd($orders)` the same results is there.